# Fastest way to see if two objects are of the same type

Tags: .net, vb.net, types

What is the fastest way to see if to objects are of the same type?

I'm now using `obj1.GetType.Equals(obj2.GetType)` but I'm hoping there is a faster way.

Comment: Is this a performance bottleneck for you?

Comment: Do you need to check for the *same* type, or are you actually interested in assignability?

Comment: @Oded According to profiling results, yes it is. It is executed quite often.

Comment: @AakashM Just checking for the same type, not assignability

Comment: Just being curious: where do you need to know if two objects are of the same type? What's your scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this way is the fastest :)

But you can write:

```
If obj1.GetType Is obj2.GetType Then

End If
```

Comment: Thanks. This made it run 21% faster. +1

Comment: I have accepted this answer assuming that it is the fastest way for now. If any faster alternative appears I will set that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note, I only know C#, but hopefully the idea will help**

Alternatively you could do:

```
obj1.GetType() == obj2.GetType()
```

Additionally, if you find yourself using this a lot, you could make an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx). Like so

```
public static bool IsSameTypeAs(this object source, object comparator)
{
    return source.GetType().Equals(comparator.GetType();
}

// usage
obj1.IsSameTypeAs(obj2)
```